# Ningun IDE me deja hacer cambios en los archivos del proyecto

Tags: laravel, vscode, phpstorm

Tengo el siguiente problema:

He instalado docker en windows mas un ubuntu desde la tienda de microsoft. Me he bajado un proyecto de git levantando los contenedores el proyecto me llega a cargar en la web.

El problema me viene cuando abro el proyecto que esta ubicado en \wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\mas la url correspondiente.

Tanto en phpstorm, como visual studio o cualquier ide no me deja guardar los cambios en archivos me salen estos mensajes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es un proyecto en laravel y tengo los permisos para escribir y demás en las carpetas pero , por lo que sea no puedo guardar desde los IDE.

Si me voy a ubuntu y hago un sudo nano al archivo si que puedo modificarlo, pero desde los ides en windows no.

Ya le di a los IDE a confiar en la carpeta en phpstorm quite el safe write y la verdad ya no se que mas hacer.

A mis compañeros no se les ocurre nada, asi que por eso recurro a vosotros.

Un saludo.